# Is there is any other method to produce a third set of collinear points rathar than the Pappus's hexagon method?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

**Pappus's hexagon theorem**: Given one set of collinear points $A,B,C$, and another set of collinear points $a,b,c$, then the intersection points $X,Y,Z$ of line pairs $Ab$ and $aB$, $Ac$ and $aC,Bc$ and $bC$ are collinear, lying on the Pappus line.

This is the known method used to produce a third set of collinear points. However, the expression for the coordinates of the points $X,Y,Z$ are very long and complicated.

My **question** is: Is there is any other **simpler** method to produce a third set of collinear points rathar than the Pappus's hexagon method?

Comment: Desargues Theorem.

Comment: @almagest: I mean a **simpler** method. The Desargues Theorem has the same comlexity.

Comment: There are *lots* of ways to generate sets of collinear points. Given $A$, $B$, $C$ collinear, let $D$ be the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$; then $A$, $B$, $D$ (and $A$, $D$, $C$) are collinear. If you need disjoint sets, let $E$ and $F$ be midpoints of $\overline{CA}$ and $\overline{AB}$; then $D$, $E$, $F$ are collinear. Desire a distinct line? Take $P$ the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$ and the $Q$ the midpoint of $\overline{bc}$, and $R$ the midpoint of $\overline{PQ}$. Could you be more specific about your requirements?

Comment: @Blue: I mean a simpler method regarding the coordinates (simple as possible) of the resulting points $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "coordinates" - what's that got to do with Pappus's theorem? The condition for three points to be collinear, given their Cartesian coordinates, is a simple "determinant = 0" condition. Are you saying, Pappus is hard, because the coordinates are hard to compute, so the determinant is hard to compute? And are you looking for theorems similar to Pappus, which can be proved by other methods but you want an "analytic geometry" proof  -  but Pappus is too difficult to put on an exam? If so, try Menelaus's theorem.

Comment: @mathguy: Yes, this is my point. Thank you.

Comment: I think you confused us all when you asked for a "third" set of collinear points. All you wanted, it seems, is "a" set of collinear points. My answer was in the spirit of "third" (meaning you already have two lines and looking for a third, meaning cubics...)  :-)

Comment: And, you can make Pappus a little easier by using a special case. For example, $A,B,C$ can be on the horizontal axis and $a,b,c$ can be on the line $y = 1$. The geometric proof is still non-trivial but the algebra is a little easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, no. Pappus and Desargues, at a deep level, follow from the properties of linear systems of cubic curves in the projective plane. By a counting argument, any cubic that contains eight of the nine intersection points of two fixed cubics must necessarily also contain the ninth intersection point as well. This and the fact that a degenerate cubic (one that is a union of curves) must be a conic and a line, or three lines, is the proof of Desargues and Pappus respectively. In that sense, there is no simpler theorem in that category - in fact there is no other theorem in that category, period.

This algebraic argument for results that seem to be pure geometry is what attracted some people to the study of algebraic geometry, a difficult but really cool field in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ell$ be the line containing $A,B,C$ and $m$ the line containing $a,b,c$.  Take any line $n$ different from $\ell$ and $m$.  Then the intersection points $Aa\cap n$, $Bb\cap n$, and $Cc\cap n$ are collinear.